# Efficient way to add Canonical tags

Tags: seo

If the value of the href for Canonical tags is populated via javascript function, would that affect the Search engine indexing (as search engines ignore javascript) ?

Comment: You should accept an answer for some more of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question as you worded it. But here's my take:

Canonical tags are used to make sure that Google (et al) knows that the same page with different URLs are, in fact, the same page.

This saves Google a lot of processing time, because it will treat those pages as a single page instead of trying to index every one of them. Also, your domain's search engine ranking will probably go up because Google doesn't think you're duplicating content.

For any page that could be duplicated because of parameters, you should include a canonical link of the page you want known as the original. So yes, it would help in your case. Though you cannot put a canonical link on someone else's domain pointing to your domain, so putting it on a partner's page would not have the intended consequences.

If you want more information, read up here: [Google Webmaster Central: Specify Your Canonical](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html)

Comment: Just to clarify, I am not looking to add any canonical tags to partners pages.

The site I am working on provides news headlines which is used in portals. Now links on my site, the url looks like
www.mydomain-name/id/12345

Now when you click on news headlines on the portal site, the url looks like www.mydomain-name/id/12345?partner=portalsite&headline=......

Its essentially the same page , additional parameters are for tracking etc.
How can canonical tags added in this case?

Comment: Then yes, you should put a canonical link on that page with www.yourdomain.com/id/12345 as the base url.

Comment: Since the pages are the same, the canonical link would be there on both versions of the page. Do you see any issues with that ?

Comment: No. That's the idea of a canonical link. You put it on ALL versions of the page that are the same.

Comment: Thats what I wanted to clarify. Thanks.

Comment: If I populate the value of the href for Canonical tags via javascript , would that affect the Search engine indexing ?